# SSIS proper handling unknown time of incoming files

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have few reports that come every day in different hours. They come unprepared in zip files. I get some accesses to SSIS to handle it but I am not skilled in it yet.

My question is how to proper handle situation with unknown time of incoming reports (I want to have them in database as soon as possible) to not burden the database/server?

- I cannot install any additional things in to SSIS or server.
- I cannot run job by sp_start_job.
- I cannot check if file is existing by SSIS.

Current my solution is that Python script is checking if file is on server and send sql procedure to insert info to db_log that file is ready. Then this prototype tSQL Task in begin of SSIS package is checking db_log, and if possible start data update:

```
    WHILE cast(GETDATE() as time(0)) < '10:00:00'
    BEGIN

        WAITFOR DELAY '00:05';
        IF EXISTS (SELECT /* CHECK LOG FOR TODAY*/ )
        BEGIN
            --INSERT TO lOG THAT PROCEDURE HAS STARTED DATA UPLOAD
            BREAK;  
        END

    END

    IF cast(GETDATE() as time(0)) > '10:00:00'
    BEGIN
        --INSERT TO lOG THAT PROCEDURE HAS FAILED - DATA NOT RECIEVED ON TIME 
        RAISERROR (15600,-1,-1, 'FATALITY');  
    END
```

but it looks like not good solution as whole loop with WAITFOR DELAY will burden the database? (As there will be 6 packages at this time)

I was thinking also on schedule Job every few minutes that will run from 5 to 10 AM try to upload data, but then there will be 1 success execution and XXX fails every day, but then there will be no waitfordelay/sleep kind of wastes.

Comment: When in the middle of a WaitFor/Delay, your code consumes almost no resources on the server. A five-second poll into a small table shouldn't burden any reasonable SQL Server.  That said, you should see if you can use the DTEXEC.EXE app, which can directly kick off the job from the command line. If so, have your Python script kick DTEXEC off to run the job directly.

Comment: it is tricky. I can have access to jobs and schedule jobs only through remote login in to server and run SSMS as local service user, and cannot install any new things.

Comment: "I cannot check if file is existing by SSIS."    Why not?